# How to use find & replace to wrap each line in document with quotations and a comma after in VS Code

Tags: json, regex, visual-studio-code

I have a bunch of data separated by lines in a file that i intend to use as JSON data. I've been able to select each line with regex using `(.+)`, but when i try to replace all with `"\1",` it just replaces it with the actual string of those characters, instead of wrapping each line in quotations and adding a comma. Is this possible in VS code?

And a "wishlist" question: I have the sets of data separated by groups. There is an empty space/new line below each group. Is there some regex i can add that wraps each line in quotes, and adds a comma after EXCEPT the last line before the empty space/new line?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Sample data below. It's just string data with some escaped quotation marks.

```
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line

data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line

data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
data example \"exampe\" line
```

**EDIT:**
Desired output below. The last line in a "set" of data not having the comma is just a "wish list" kind of thing. Won't be a huge deal for me to remove the last line's comma. Really just want each line/string to be surround by quotes and comma at the end.

```
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line"

"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line"

"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line",
"data example \"exampe\" line"
```

Comment: Can you please post the code your are using and a sample of the input text?

Comment: @Dror Sure, ill add it to the original post. It's just string data on each line that i want surrounded in quotes for JSON.

Comment: Can you please post also desired output and if you are attempting to do this with a single regex?

Comment: @Dror Added to my post.

Comment: And if possible for a single regex sure. But whatever works. I just don't want to manually add quotations and commas to every line of data in the document.

Comment: why don't you use multi cursor. You can select the lines who you want to remove commas by selecting `,LFLF` and then `Ctrl-L, Right, Left, Left, BackSpace`

Comment: `^.+` is the regex, `"$1",` is the replacement

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew! that worked... any recommendation for a regex to select a comma followed by a new line? Something like `,/n`

Comment: `,\n\n` this seems to do the trick. thanks